# How to distinguish HTTP 1.1 from HTTP 2.0 using Snort rules

Tags: http, metadata, http2, snort

I'm struggling with the task of auditing TCP packets using Snort IDS.
The goal is: send audit event (1) on some content (2) depending on HTTP protocol version. But I can't handle it with the means of Snort.

Using Snort 2.9.17 I've tried the approach based on `metadata: service` keyword in Snort rules:

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"Alert HTTP 1.1"; file_data; content:"apple"; metadata: service http; priority:130; sid:1000001;)
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"Alert HTTP 2.0"; file_data; content:"apple"; metadata: service http2; priority:130; sid:1000002;)
```

After that I try to get 2 web-pages (with HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 2.0 versions) via browser, but 2 rules are triggered on both pages. I was expecting, that rule for HTTP 2.0 will trigger on HTTP 2.0 web-page, and rule for HTTP 1.1 on its own page.

Also I've noticed, that if rules do not have `content` field, than they are triggered on the first TCP-packet of each connection (TCP ACK packet), meaning, that rule field `metadata` had not been taken into account - and filtering was done based on only protocol field (`tcp`).

Could anyone, please, tell me, does Snort 2.9 support http2 protocol? What could be wrong in this approach? Does anyone know, how HTTP 1.1/2.0 could be identified by Snort with other means?
I would appreciate any help.

P.S. As HTTP 2.0 works over TLS, I decrypt such packets in DAQ-module and send them to Snort in plain text, so it should be able to analize its contents